# Argument evaluation in c

Tags: c

```
 void main(){
     int i=10;
     int j=5;
     int k=0;

     k = MAN(i++,++j);
     printf("%d %d %d ", i, j, k);
 }
```

Can anyone explain how the answer has been evaluated?
MAN is a function.I want to know the sequence of how the arguments are being evaluated.I am getting the answer as 12 6 11.

Comment: Not until you tell us what `MAN` is.

Comment: Also, the answer is probably "undefined behaviour", since `MAN` will most likely be something like `#define MAN(a,b) a + b + a + b`.

Comment: It is a FAQ. [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) probably.

Comment: it need not be undefined behaviour! we do not know neither the answer nor the definition of MAN.

Comment: @PeterMiehle What's the point of giving an answer two an unclear question and then complaining about _comments_ making exactly the assumptions you made for your “answer”.

Comment: What output are you *expecting*, what output are you *getting*, and what is the definition of `MAN`?  Unless you provide that information, you're not going to get very helpful answers.

Comment: we still do not know the definition of MAN()!

Answer (score 2):

Please note that operators, sequence points, and order of evaluation are fairly basic things that all should have been covered by whatever book or document you are using to learn the language.

The postincrement operator (a `++` following a variable name) will increment the value of the variable and evaluate the the previous value. In other words, if `i` has the value `10`, then `i++` will evaluate to `10`, and `i` will have the new value of `11`.

The preincrement operator (a `++` before a variable name) will increment the value of the variable and evaluate the the new value. In other words, if `j` has the value `5`, then `++j` will evaluate to `6` and `j` with have the new value of `6`.

If, as you say, `MAN()` is a function in your code and not a function-like macro, then your claimed result of `12 6 11` is impossible, because you start with `i=10`, then `i++` gives `i` the value of `11`, so when you pass it to `printf()` there's simply no way to get a `12` out of it. Therefore, it must be that `MAN()` is a function-like macro, which evaluates at least one of its arguments more than once.

Please provide the actual definition of `MAN()` that your code is using.

Comment: min(x,y) as a macro (x<y?x:y) is not undefined behaviour! it is side-effects, the arguemnts are evaluated in deterministic order with deterministic results (but not the intended)

Comment: And where did I say anything about that? The questioner is asking about "`MAN()`". Not `min()`, `MAN()`. Granted that a `min()` macro defined as you show it is not undefined behavior, I don't see the questioner asking that (unless he decides to show the definition of `MAN()` in his code.

Comment: Looking over it again, I see that even without the specific `min()` macro that you're assuming the questioner is using, my statement about undefined behavior was still wrong. I have removed that statement.